# Puppeteer working from terminal but failing from crontab

Tags: cron, puppeteer, grafana

looking for help from experts. When running Puppeteer from terminal, it just works as expected and generate the pdf file (part of the script is `const browser = await puppeteer.launch();`)

**Running via shell generate the pdf file**

```
$ /bin/sh /tmp/grafana_report_pup.sh
```

**grafana_report_pup.sh**

```
node /tmp/grafana_pdf.js http://localhost:3000/d/qP-sbQEZz/new-dashboard?kiosk $GF_USER:$GF_PASSWORD $GF_OUT
```

The issue became when I put to crontab:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
44 10 * * * /bin/sh /tmp/grafana_report_pup.sh  > /tmp/graf.log 2>&1
```

I was getting an error about no sandbox, therefore I was suggested to pass arguments:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']});
```

Even using suggested arguments, running from crontab generate below error

```
(node:56385) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of undefined
    at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:2:67
    at ExecutionContext._evaluateInternal (/tmp/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/ExecutionContext.js:122:13)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
  -- ASYNC --
    at ExecutionContext.<anonymous> (/tmp/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:111:15)
    at DOMWorld.evaluate (/tmp/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/DOMWorld.js:112:20)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
  -- ASYNC --
    at Frame.<anonymous> (/tmp/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:111:15)
    at Page.evaluate (/tmp/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Page.js:860:43)
    at Page.<anonymous> (/tmp/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/helper.js:112:23)
    at /tmp/grafana_pdf.js:59:30
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:56385) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:56385) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

[Link to grafana_pdf.js](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/svet-b/1ad0656cd3ce0e1a633e16eb20f66425/raw/29ea176e055710bfc50834f4816377a26e890927/grafana_pdf.js)

Comment: How about adding some `waitForSelector` before the evaluate?

Comment: I was not able to root cause the problem but when using values instead of environment variables `$GF_USER:$GF_PASSWORD $GF_OUT`, crontab works just fine.

Comment: Check this out: https://askubuntu.com/a/239511/505581 Can it be related to our problem?